# Slick projection <> to a trait with companion object

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm new to Scala & Slick and am having some trouble implementing user accounts.

**User class & companion object:**

```
case class User(id: Long, email: String, password: String, role: Role)

object User {
}
```

**Role trait & companion object:**

```
sealed trait Role

object Role {
    case object Administrator extends Role
    case object NormalUser extends Role
}
```

**UserRepository Schema config**

```
import javax.inject.{ Inject, Singleton }
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile

import scala.concurrent.{ Future, ExecutionContext }

@Singleton
class UserRepository @Inject() (dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
  private val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
  import dbConfig._
  import profile.api._

  private class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def email = column[String]("email")
    def password = column[String]("password")
    def role = column[String]("role")

    def * = (id, email, password, role) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, (User.unapply _))
  }
```

I'm getting a type mismatch on `User.apply` and `User.unapply`

```
[error]  found   : ((Long, String, String, models.Role)) => models.User
[error]  required: ((Long, String, String, String)) => ?
[error]     def * = (id, email, password, role) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, (User.unapply _))
```

I've tried writing my own function type as suggested in the slick documentation <sup>[1](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/schemas.html#mapped-tables)</sup> as well as creating a custom scalar type using `MappedColumnType` <sup>[2](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.1.0/userdefined.html#using-custom-scalar-types-in-queries)</sup> but neither seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is here:

```
def role = column[String]("role")
```

There should be `Role` instead of `String`.

Comment: Unfortunately this returns:  'could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[models.Role]`

I tried adding this in the `UserRepository` class: `implicit val roleColumn = MappedColumnType.base[Role, String](
        { r => if (r == Role.Administrator) "Administrator" else "NormalUser" },
        { s => if (s == "Administrator") Role.Administrator else Role.NormalUser }
       )`
but sbConfig escapes it's defining scope.

Comment: @phil
Well, this is a different issue. If you want slick to work with `Role` you must anyway define `implicit val roleColumn = ...`
For example you can remove modifier `private` at `dbConfig`. Or make it no so strict: `private[...]`.